# (QT) this application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b

Tags: c++, qt

In QT my application work correctly and it compiled but i deploy to windows i am getting error and i already pasted the dll files in binary file path.

"this application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b".

for example i done this using cmd.

C:\Qt\Qt6.2.4\6.2.4\mingw_64\bin>windeployqt.exe c:\Qt\Qt6.2.4\Examples\Qt-6.2.4\quick3d\build-principledmaterial-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\principledmaterial.exe

kindly help me the solution.

Comment: can show us  if any dll is missing? you can use dependency walker http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I solved it by again coping dll and replacing them with new after compiled.

Answer (score -1):

I copied the following files from the Qt compiler (**C:\Qt\6.2.7\mingw_64\bin**) and replaced the files in the application repo.

> libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
>
> libstdc++ 6.dll
>
> libwinthread-1.dll